# i am getting wrong answer with if else block

Tags: java, if-statement

I am comparing two strings in if else block..if it is true **if** block should be executed and if it is false **else** block should execute..but my code is always executing **else** block for both true & false condition..here is my code

```
if(deckey==keystr)
{
.
.
}
else
{
System.out.println("your unauthorised person");
System.exit(0);
}
```

my deckey is containing string value abc123 and for keystr i am getting the value from this which is also abc123(i am getting through arraylist)..

```
ArrayList<Integer> listfkey= new ArrayList<Integer>();
String keystr=" ";
for (int i = 0; i < listfkey.size(); i++) {
dech=(char)listfkey.get(i).intValue();
keystr+=dech;
}
```

please help me out..

Comment: Comparing strings like this will not end well: all you're doing is comparing the references. Use .equals method instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Please don't downvote well-posed questions that are duplicates (unless of course the answer could easily be attained with a search). Vote to close instead.

Answer (score 3):

Strings need to be tested for equality using the `.equals` method:

```
deckey.equals(keystr)
```

Not the `==` operator, which tests if two string *instances* are the same:

```
deckey==keystr
```

Comment: you can also use `deckey.equalsIgnoresCase(keystr)` so it doesn't care about upper/lower case. Also its a good idea to do a empty/null check before working with any String: `StringUtils.isEmpty(deckey) || StringUtils.isEmpty(keystr)`.

Answer (score 0):

primatives are a different matter, but with Java objects, == will only return true if the object is being compared to itself (same memory location). For Objects, use the `equals` method or the `Comparator` interface

Answer (score 0):

== is use for compare memory location, it will be right on some primitive data

String is object, so for compare it we need to use .equals() method
It come from Comparator